# Hashtags must link to a Twitter search with the hashtag as the query

Tags: twitter

[Hashtags must link to a Twitter search with the hashtag as the query](https://developer.twitter.com/en/developer-terms/display-requirements)

Which url do I have to link to a hashtag?

---

**For example # hoge**

plan1.https://twitter.com/search?q=hoge

plan2.https://twitter.com/hashtag/hoge?src=hash

plan3.https://twitter.com/hashtag/hoge

Or any one of the above ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plan 2 and plan 3 work, but the way that Twitter's [twitter-text library](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text) autolinks hashtags, would produce this (instead of your suggested plan 1):

`https://twitter.com/search?q=%23hoge`

Comment: Which plan do you think should be accessed according to the twitter rules?　plan1?

Comment: plan4 - the one I just described - would be most compliant with expectations.

Comment: I decided to implement it with this answer plan.